# Move App Engine app to another region

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Is there a way to move an App Engine application from US to EU? By mistake I created the app in the US.

Now the database and the buckets are already in this app (EU) but the servers are in US.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this. You will need to create a new project, then click advanced options to select the app engine location.